# Change background image using JQuery

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to change the background image of a div.

I have stored the image in a variable but am unsure of how to pass this as it is a variable and not a straight forward file path.

```
var bgImage = $('#box').find('img');

$('#box2').css('background-image', url(bgImage));
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`bgImage` is not a path, it's a reference to the `img` element. You'll want to access the value of its `src` attribute; `attr('src')`.

Also, you're currently using your code as though you're calling a function called `url()`, passing the image to it, while you in fact want to pass the *string* value `url(...)`. You'll have to do some string concatenation, as such:

```
$('#box2').css('background-image', 'url(' + bgImage.attr('src') + ')');
```

Answer (score 3):

Your syntax is wrong. Have this instead:

```
$('#box2').css('background-image', "url(" + bgImage.attr("src") + ")");
```

Anyhow, you better check you got something:

```javascript
if (bgImage.length == 1) {
    $('#box2').css('background-image', "url(" + bgImage.attr("src") + ")");
}
```

Comment: Why are you preferring `prop` over `attr` in this example?

Comment: @David - I wrongly assumed `.prop()` replaced `.attr()` but now after reading deeper saw it's true only for property values (e.g. `tagName`) while image `src` is classic attribute. Edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#box2').css('background-image', 'url(' + bgImage.attr('src') + ')');
```

Answer (score 0):

The second parameter of CSS has to be text aswel:

```
$('#box2').css('background-image', 'url(' + bgImage.attr('src') + ')');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#box2').css('background-image', 'url('+bgImage.attr("src")+') 0px 0px');
```

You must pass it in a string like that

Answer (score -1):

Use Firebug to inspect your element. See what the new background-image is set to.

And you are missing some quotes

> $('#box2').css('background-image', 'url(\''+bgImage+'\')');